# How to use function to verify password inside sqlalchemy query?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

How to use function to verify password inside sqlalchemy query ?
In

```
class PersonModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    username = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(75), nullable=False)
    password = Column(String(128), nullable=False)
```

I store password using `sha256_crypt.encrypt("password_string")` from [http://pythonhosted.org](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/)/passlib/ and I can verify with `sha256_crypt.verify(password_to_check_against, hash)`

( tried like

```
person = session.query(PersonModel).filter(and_(PersonModel.username.like(username), PersonModel.password.like(sha256_crypt.encrypt(password_string)))).first()
```

but it doesn't work => sha256_crypt.encrypt(password_string) generates different value than in db for same password and I cannot use `==` operator only `sha256_crypt.verify` from site)
How to inject this in my query ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `sha256_crypt.verify()`, and you can't do it in an `AND` clause because it needs password hash string for verification.

If you look at an example of the output for this function, and the [documentation for "modular crypt format"](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/modular_crypt_format.html#modular-crypt-format):

> $5$rounds=80000$zvpXD3gCkrt7tw.1$QqeTSolNHEfgryc5oMgiq1o8qCEAcmye3FoMSuvgToC

- The `5` at the beginning [means sha256_crypt](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/modular_crypt_format.html#mcf-identifiers).
- `rounds=80000` is how many times it was hashed.
- The next section between the `$`'s is the salt.
- The last section is actually [the digest output](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/modular_crypt_format.html#requirements)

So it actually needs all of those first three parts, plus the plain-text password to hash it the same way.

To do this, first get your user's information:

```
person = session.query(PersonModel).filter(PersonModel.username.like(username)).first()
```

Then do the verification:

```
is_authenticated = sha256_crypt.verify(password_string, person.password)
```